# pandas matplotlib .plot(kind='hist') vs .plot(kind='bar') issue

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram, bar-chart

I have a pandas dataframe named `firstperiod` and a column named `megaball`. The range of the values in `megaball` are from 1 to 25, and this line of code:

```
print firstperiod.megaball.value_counts().sort_index()
```

gives me this, which is what I want to see (the # of occurrences per possible value)

```
1     12
2      4
3      9
4      4
5      3
6      6
7      5
8      8
9      7
10    10
11     6
12     5
13     3
14     5
15     6
16     8
17    15
18     7
19     8
20     5
21     8
22     7
23     1
24    11
25     9


firstperiod.megaball.value_counts().sort_index().plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

^this shows me a bar chart just fine, with x-axis values up to 25, y-axis values up to 15.

But for some reason, when I want a histogram instead of a bar chart (and change just the parameter value for `kind=`, this gives me something totally incorrect and very different from the bar chart values earlier. Why is that? and how to fix the histogram?

```
firstperiod.megaball.value_counts().sort_index().plot(kind='hist')
plt.show()
```

Comment: What histogram do you want? Do you want a second-order histogram, i.e., counts of the counts? Or do you just want to group your current barchart in bins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the "hist" plot is not just plotting data, but actually first estimating the empirical distribution of the raw data and then plotting the result. That is, "hist" is going to bin the data, count the instances per bin and plot that, so there is no need of doing the `value_counts()` ourselves.

Therefore, the equivalent of:

```
firstperiod.megaball.value_counts().sort_index().plot(kind='bar')
```

Should just be:

```
firstperiod.megaball.plot(kind='hist')
```

Comment: This can be simplified as: 

`firstperiod.megaball.hist()`

Read more here http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.hist.html